# Google Maps Platform server rejected your request using rstudio

Tags: r, google-api, ggmap

I am working in R studio. I have created a project in google cloud, activated an API, and enabled the Maps Static API restriction.   There is an orange triangle on the Google Cloud Console that says "configure consent screen," but when I click on that, my only option is to fill out APP info. I am not creating an app. I do not know why the key is invalid.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the steps I took in R:
I registered the API with ggmap,

```
register_google(key = "[key code]", write = TRUE)
```

but when I enter this code:

```
chicagomap<- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 41.8781, lat = 87.6298),
                             zoom = 10, maptype = 'roadmap',
                              color = 'color'))
```

I get this error:

> Error in get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 41.8781, lat = 87.6298), zoom
> = 10,  :    HTTP 400 Bad Request The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. The provided API key is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled the correct APIs? For ggmap, I used the Geocoding and Maps Static APIs. Not sure if you need both, but my point is double check you have actually enabled the APIs you need.

Comment: I have enabled Geocoding, Maps Static, Maps embed, and Geolocation APIs. I have them all checked off in the restrictions. I am not sure what else to do. I continue to get the same error message.

Comment: The issue was in my code, not with the API. I found a workaround. Thank you for your help.